# Reading and writing into the same file with FileInputStream and FileOutputStream

Tags: java, eof, java-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

The problem with my code is an ***infinite loop*** of reading and writing.

I can't find a solution or a concept for this problem.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("toto.txt");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("toto.txt",false);

int m;
while ((m = in.read()) != 0) {
    System.out.print(m);
    out.write(m);
}
        
in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: The problem is that `read()` returns -1 and end of stream, not zero. Your loop could terminate at any time with binary data: with text data it will never terminate because there should be no null characters. However reading and writing the same file will never work anyway. On Windows you will be prevented from opening the `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

alter the loop condition to below:

```
while ((m = in.read()) != -1)
```

Comment: Correct but you should provide an explanation.

Comment: Ok, you can see the JavaDoc of FileInputStream#read().                                        
Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available.
Returns:
the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with my code in an infinite loop of reading and writing. I
> can't find a solution or a concept for this problem.

There's a number of problems with your code:

- The file will be treated as empty after the `FileOutputStream` gets instantiated because you've set `append` flag to `false`. End method `read()` will always return `-1` because there's no content to read.
- Condition is incorrect and method `read()` and only because of that control enters the loop and EOF (`-1`) is being repeatedly written into the file. If you fixed the condition to `(m = in.read()) != -1`, the loop would be ignored because the file is blank from the start.
- If you would do both: fix the condition and change the `append` flag to `true` then you would get another flavor of infinite loop. All the contents of the file will be successfully read and repeatedly appended to the file.

So at any condition, reading and writing simultaneously to the same file isn't a good idea.

One important note in regard to exception handling.

Because there's no `catch` block in your code snippet, I assume that you've added a `throws` to the main() - it's not a nice idea. Methods `close()` in your code will be invoked only in case of successful execution, but if exception occur resources will never get released.

Instead, I suggest you to make use of [**try with resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). That will provide an implicit finally block for you that will take care of closing the resources regardless whether exception occurred or not (now your invocations of `close()` will not get executed in case of exception). Another option is to declare `finally` block explicitly, and close the resources inside it.

Try with resource is more concise and cleaner way to ensure that resources will get released.

Also consider wrapping both streams with buffered high-level streams to improve performance. It'll significantly reduce the number of time your application will need to access the file system.

```
    try (var in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("source.txt"));
         var out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("destination.txt", false))) {

        int next; // a subsequent byte that has been read from the source
        while ((next = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(next);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It goes into an infinite loop because reads will see the results of past writes.

Reading and Writing the same file using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream is not possible. Use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) if you want to read/write to the same file. You can specify the position as well if you want to write at a specific place in your file.

If you want to write to the end of the file and then read all the lines on the file then here is a sample for that:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("toto.txt", "rw");
file.seek(file.length());
file.writeBytes("This is a temp file");
file.seek(0); //sets the pointer to the first byte
String line;
while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: This will not read all the lines in the file. It won't read anything, as the file is already positioned at its end.

Comment: But after all that, this is still not what the OP is trying to do.